# How to Configure Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates to fetch certificate from key vault in .Net 6 C#

Tags: .net-6.0, azure-keyvault

I have .Net 6 API.
I have one app registration (Client ID, secret, Scope) which I use to fetch secrets from Key vault. Now while configuring Identity Server, I want to pass X509Certificate2 type certificate in AddSigningCredential. Can anyone help me how to fetch certificate in .Net 6 and convert it to X509Certificate2 . It's already uploaded to Key Vault.
I am looking for solution which can be deployed to Production also

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this example: https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault-example-dotnet/blob/66c5052a2fc7651d1d86f4ff8b540d60ac1569d7/dotnet-core/src/AzureKeyVaultCertificateRepository.cs#L30-L35

```
    private X509Certificate2 GetPfx()
    {
        var base64Value = _secretClient.GetSecret(_certificateName).Value.Value;
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Value);
        return new X509Certificate2(bytes, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    }
```

This is the code using it: https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault-example-dotnet/blob/66c5052a2fc7651d1d86f4ff8b540d60ac1569d7/dotnet-core/test/Tests.cs#L82-L116

```
    public void TestGetCertificateDetailsShouldReturnValidData()
    {
        //given
        const string certificateName = "certificate";
        const string subject = "CN=example.com";
        TokenCredential credential = new NoopCredentials();
        var secretClientOptions = new SecretClientOptions(SecretClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V7_3)
        {
            DisableChallengeResourceVerification = true
        };
        var certificateClientOptions = new CertificateClientOptions(CertificateClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V7_3)
        {
            DisableChallengeResourceVerification = true
        };
        var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://localhost:8443/"), credential, GetClientOptions(secretClientOptions));
        var certificateClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri("https://localhost:8443/"), credential, GetClientOptions(certificateClientOptions));
        var certificatePolicy = new CertificatePolicy("Self", subject)
        {
            KeyType = CertificateKeyType.Ec,
            KeyCurveName = CertificateKeyCurveName.P256,
            Exportable = true,
            ContentType = CertificateContentType.Pkcs12,
            ValidityInMonths = 12
        };
        certificateClient.StartCreateCertificate(certificateName, certificatePolicy).WaitForCompletion();
        var underTest = new AzureKeyVaultCertificateRepository(secretClient, certificateName);
        
        //when
        var actualCertificate = underTest.GetCertificate();
        var actualPrivateKey = underTest.GetPrivateKey();

        //then
        Assert.AreEqual(subject, actualCertificate.Subject);
        Assert.NotNull(actualPrivateKey);
    }
```

Not sure how prod-ready it is (I am not that familiar with .Net).

Comment: Thanks, I have used permalinks exactly for this reason. This way it cannot change, only disappear (which I know it won't because the repo is mine).

Answer (score 1):

To load the certificate INCLUDING the private key, you need to retrieve it as a secret, not a certificate. If you get it as a certificate, you only get it with its public key.

this is the code I use to get a complete certificate back from Azure Key Vault and you can then pass the retrieved X509Certificate2 certificate to AddSigningCredential.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Load a certificate (with private key) from Azure Key Vault
    ///
    /// Getting a certificate with private key is a bit of a pain, but the code below solves it.
    /// 
    /// Get the private key for Key Vault certificate
    /// https://github.com/heaths/azsdk-sample-getcert
    /// 
    /// See also these GitHub issues: 
    /// https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12742
    /// https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12083
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config"></param>
    /// <param name="certificateName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(IConfiguration config, string certificateName)
    {
        string vaultUrl = config["Vault:Url"] ?? "";
        string clientId = config["Vault:ClientId"] ?? "";
        string tenantId = config["Vault:TenantId"] ?? "";
        string secret = config["Vault:ClientSecret"] ?? "";

        Console.WriteLine($"Loading certificate '{certificateName}' from Azure Key Vault");

        var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId: tenantId, clientId: clientId, clientSecret: secret);
        var certClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri(vaultUrl), credentials);
        var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultUrl), credentials);

        var cert = GetCertificateAsync(certClient, secretClient, certificateName);

        Console.WriteLine("Certificate loaded");
        return cert;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Helper method to get a certificate
    /// 
    /// Source https://github.com/heaths/azsdk-sample-getcert/blob/master/Program.cs
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="certificateClient"></param>
    /// <param name="secretClient"></param>
    /// <param name="certificateName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateAsync(CertificateClient certificateClient,
                                                            SecretClient secretClient,
                                                            string certificateName)
    {

        KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificate = certificateClient.GetCertificate(certificateName);

        // Return a certificate with only the public key if the private key is not exportable.
        if (certificate.Policy?.Exportable != true)
        {
            return new X509Certificate2(certificate.Cer);
        }

        // Parse the secret ID and version to retrieve the private key.
        string[] segments = certificate.SecretId.AbsolutePath.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (segments.Length != 3)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Number of segments is incorrect: {segments.Length}, URI: {certificate.SecretId}");
        }

        string secretName = segments[1];
        string secretVersion = segments[2];

        KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.GetSecret(secretName, secretVersion);

        // For PEM, you'll need to extract the base64-encoded message body.
        // .NET 5.0 preview introduces the System.Security.Cryptography.PemEncoding class to make this easier.
        if ("application/x-pkcs12".Equals(secret.Properties.ContentType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            byte[] pfx = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value);
            return new X509Certificate2(pfx);
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException($"Only PKCS#12 is supported. Found Content-Type: {secret.Properties.ContentType}");
    }
}
```